# PHP/curl: namelookup_time/dns slowing requests

Tags: php, curl, dns, ipv6

EDIT: Found part of the cause - see bottom.

I'm doing a standard curl call from php.  However, there seems to be a hangup during name resolution.
On my OSX box, the namelookup_time is over 1 second consistently for this and other queries to the same subnet.
A linux box on my subnet doing the same query has a 0.02 second response to the other subnet, so it's a problem with my box.

This is a problem since our app makes many calls to this subnet to build a page, so the seconds add up.

My curl_getinfo response (url snipped out)

```
array
  'url' => string ' < SNIPPED > '... (length=1449)
  'content_type' => string 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' (length=25)
  'http_code' => int 200
  'header_size' => int 227
  'request_size' => int 1480
  'filetime' => int -1
  'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
  'redirect_count' => int 0
  'total_time' => float 1.165444
  'namelookup_time' => float 1.001272
  'connect_time' => float 1.017765
  'pretransfer_time' => float 1.017781
  'size_upload' => float 0
  'size_download' => float 92562
  'speed_download' => float 79422
  'speed_upload' => float 0
  'download_content_length' => float 92562
  'upload_content_length' => float 0
  'starttransfer_time' => float 1.043094
  'redirect_time' => float 0
  'certinfo' => 
    array
      empty
  'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
```

I have a suspicion that the name lookup lag is due to IPv6, so I tried the following:

1) Followed the directions here to turn off Ipv6 on OSX, including reboot.  I set all instances of IPv6 to **INACTIVE** like the article suggested.

http://community.centrify.com/t5/Express-for-Mac-Tips-and-Tricks/Using-local-domains-with-Centrify-Directcontrol-on-the-Mac/ba-p/3724

I confirmed that my Mac didn't have IPv6 support here: http://ipv6test.google.com/.

2) Rebuilt PHP with --disable-ipv6.

php -i shows: IPv6 Support => disabled

although in the curl section, it says "IPv6 => Yes", and I don't know how to surgically turn this off.

3) Ran this before the curl call:

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );

Unfortunately, none of the above steps worked - I'm still getting 1 sec+ name resolution times. Does anyone have any troubleshooting suggestions, or better yet, a magic bullet? :)

(Note - I've googled and SO'ed this question, but to no avail..)

Edit: answering ckhan's questions below:
1) I get the same 1 sec+ namelookup_time using an IP address or a FQDN:

```
'url' => string 'HTTP://172.19.105.171:8070  <SNIPPED> '... (length=1439)
...
'namelookup_time' => float 1.001309
```

2) The command line client doesn't have the same problem:

```
# url.txt has the same url as the above curl call
time cat url.txt |xargs curl
<... response output ...>
real  0m0.053s
user  0m0.009s
sys 0m0.008s
```

3) dig seems to have no problem with accessing the server.

```
dig 172.19.105.171
...
;; Query time: 77 msec
...
```

My environment:
PHP 5.3.8
OSX 10.7.3

**Partial solution**

The app code is using curl_multi_select, which has a default timeout of 1 second.
Changing this delay to 0.00005 seconds makes the call return much faster.  So that's what's causing the delay.  However, I don't yet know why this is different on Linux vs OSX or the particular flavor of php/libcurl that I have built (5.3.8).

Comment: 3 questions: 1) Have you verified that using IP address instead of name is fast? 2) Can you get PHP out of the loop, and confirm that just using curl command line client has the same problem? 3) can you get curl out of the loop, and confirm that nslookup/dig are slow?

Comment: I'd run traceroute and compare to the fast linux box - they really are on the same subnet, right?

Comment: Good thinking. I did compare them earlier, the traceroute times were comparable (15-30 ms), not 1 sec+ though.

Comment: Check ping times, and if those are comparable - then back to #2 - is it all networking, or just PHP ?

Comment: Ping times are comparable - 3ms on the linux box, and 15ms on my osx box (although I'm currently VPNed in, I have the same problems while in the office).  Since the dig, ping, and command line curl times are ok, it seems to be related to PHP/libcurl, but I can't yet determine what.

Comment: If the stats still indicate that the time is going to namelookup even when using IP address I think probably best to do a wireshark trace.

Comment: Could also dtruss it, and get relative timestamps on the system calls. Just looking over curl sources now... you're not using a proxy are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP app code is using curl_multi_select, which has a default timeout of 1 second. Changing this delay to 0.00005 seconds makes the call return much faster. So that's what's causing the delay. However, I don't yet know why this is different on Linux vs OSX or the particular flavor of php/libcurl that I have built (5.3.8).

I'm going to open a different SO question to try to resolve the curl_multi_select issue.

Comment: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747626/how-can-i-prevent-curl-multi-select-from-hanging-on-osx

Answer (score 0):

You can fixed your domain in /etc/hosts, then php curl don't need to lookup DNS to find ip address. That worked for me.