# PHP cURL IPv6 connect_time very slow on first request

Tags: php, http, curl, ipv6

I'm trying to make a PHP script that generates and assigns a random IPv6 address to eth0 and does a HTTP request, but it seems like all addresses need to be "initialized" by first making a dummy request. However, I need the IP to be ready for a HTTP request within a second from creation. After hours and hours of testing and searching the internet I couldn't figure out the problem so I came here.

My Debian VPS has a /64 IPv6 address space assigned to it.

To explain the problem I did this:

First I manually assign 9 IPs

```
ip addr change 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:1 dev eth0 valid_lft 600 preferred_lft 600                       
ip addr change 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:2 dev eth0 valid_lft 600 preferred_lft 600                       
ip addr change 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:3 dev eth0 valid_lft 600 preferred_lft 600                       
ip addr change 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:4 dev eth0 valid_lft 600 preferred_lft 600                       
ip addr change 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:5 dev eth0 valid_lft 600 preferred_lft 600                       
ip addr change 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:6 dev eth0 valid_lft 600 preferred_lft 600                       
ip addr change 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:7 dev eth0 valid_lft 600 preferred_lft 600                       
ip addr change 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:8 dev eth0 valid_lft 600 preferred_lft 600                       
ip addr change 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:9 dev eth0 valid_lft 600 preferred_lft 600
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
$URL = "ipv6.whatismyv6.com";

for($i=1; $i<10; $i++)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    $IP = "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:{$i}";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);

    // Set IPv6
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $IP);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

    print "IP {$IP}\n";

    curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch))
        die(curl_error($ch));

    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
    print "\nDone for IP {$IP}\n\n";

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

On the first run of the script I get this output. As you can see connect_time is 32 seconds on each except the first request. It looks as if cURL takes its time for 30 seconds before trying to connect.

```
IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:1
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(2.041753)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.969251)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(2.002953)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(2.002985)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(708)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(2.04171)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:1"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(46353)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:1

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:2
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(32.02449)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(3.1E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(31.986268)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(31.986298)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(45)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.024464)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:2"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(53907)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:2

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:3
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(32.080273)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(1.9E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(32.041328)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.041358)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(45)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.080247)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:3"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(56910)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:3

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:4
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(32.124284)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(1.9E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(32.085118)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.085152)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(45)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.124239)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:4"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(59346)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:4

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:5
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(32.074903)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(1.6E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(32.036185)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.036232)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(45)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.074879)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:5"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(50604)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:5

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:6
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(32.425055)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.35623)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(32.386056)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.386088)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(44)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.425031)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:6"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(35632)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:6

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:7
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(35.150028)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(2.0E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(35.111304)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(35.111331)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(41)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(35.149998)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:7"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(54827)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:7

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:8
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(32.09912)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(2.0E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(32.06125)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.061287)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(45)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.099082)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:8"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(45077)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:8

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:9
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(32.050919)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(2.4E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(32.011934)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.01196)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(45)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(32.050894)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:9"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(48069)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:9
```

I ran the script immidiately after the first run was done and this was the output this time. Now the connect_time is all good and I'd want it to be this way on the first request too.

```
IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:1
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(1.00357)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.93072)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.966039)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.966092)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(1440)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(1.003512)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:1"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(42623)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:1

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:2
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.074783)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(1.6E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.035955)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.035979)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(19335)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.07476)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:2"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(60928)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:2

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:3
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.076524)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(2.2E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.03672)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.036757)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(18896)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.076497)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:3"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(37292)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:3

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:4
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.074629)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(2.1E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.035955)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.036001)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(19375)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.074593)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:4"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(53553)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:4

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:5
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.074592)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(2.0E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.036058)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.036093)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(19385)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.074564)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:5"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(51041)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:5

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:6
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.074324)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(1.9E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.035745)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.035784)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(19455)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.074282)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:6"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(37542)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:6

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:7
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.07241)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(2.3E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.035187)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.035246)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(19969)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.072382)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:7"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(50575)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:7

IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:8
array(27) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(26) "HTTP://ipv6.whatismyv6.com"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(174)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(58)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.074898)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(2.1E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.036041)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.036079)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(19306)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(1446)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.074861)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "2001:4810::110"
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(33) "2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:8"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(58766)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(58) "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ipv6.whatismyv6.com
Accept: */*

"
}

Done for IP 2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:2:8
```

Also,

```
wget --bind-address=2001:19f0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:3:1 http://ipv6.whatismyv6.com
```

works just fine like the first request in the PHP script.

I've been battling with this for days so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even after the addresses run out of being valid, I can add them back and the requests will still work just fine.

Comment: A packet capture would provide some hints about what is happening.

Comment: @kasperd I didn't even think about this. I took my time to dump the traffic with tcpdump, opened it up in wireshark and took a screenshot. I feel like this shows the problem but I don't know nearly enough about networking and its terminology to continue on fixing this myself. The TCP handshake seems to fail because the neighboring stuff comes in 30 seconds late. But is this a problem with my network configuration or PHP? http://i.imgur.com/RUWPL9o.png

Comment: A problem can be seen already with the first two packets. From the SYN is sent there is almost a second of delay before the neighbor solicitation is sent. The neighbor solicitation appears to be triggered by the need to send a SYN ACK back. But that delay should only have been a single roundtrip, and from the GET request and response we can see that the roundtrip is actually less than 40ms. It does not appear to be a problem on the client side. Can you get a capture closer to the server?

Comment: What do you mean by a capture closer to the server? If you mean the target HTTP server it's just a random IPv6 enabled website I used for the test and the tcp dump looks about the same on all IPv6 websites. Can the problem be on my server provider's side so should I contact them?

Comment: If you always see a one second delay between the initial SYN and the neighbor solicitation triggered by the SYN-ACK regardless of which server you connect to, then I suspect the problem lies on the router you are connected to. The router might be delaying all neighbor solicitation messages for some obscure reason. You should ask the provider for a routed prefix. A routed prefix would be much better suited for your use case than using addresses from within your link prefix. It will reduce the neighbor discovery traffic on the router and likely solve your problem that way.

Comment: The problem was indeed at my server provider's IPv6 setup and they won't be changing it for me. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Good news: There are tons of providers to chose from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP/curl: namelookup\_time/dns slowing requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731877/php-curl-namelookup-time-dns-slowing-requests)

Answer (score 1):

After adding an IPv6 address the system usually does duplicate address detection (DAD) to make sure no other system is using the same address. This can take a few seconds. If you really need to be able to use the address right away you need to disable DAD on the interface:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_dad
```

Comment: If this means the IP address stays in tentative state for a while I was already aware of it. That's not the issue here, though. I can wait for multiple minutes and the result will still be the same. I'm thinking it's a PHP related bug/problem.
Thanks for this, though, I was wondering how to do that too.

Comment: Ok, then it is indeed something else!